# custom http hook using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to create my first custom hook but I am not sure if I am on the right track here. Probably not, which is why I am asking.. First of all, I am not sure if the cancel token will work like this or if I need to use it when I actually use this hook in a component.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

export default useApi = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const request = async () => {
    const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source();
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await Axios(url, options);
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(error);
    }
    return () => {
      ourRequest.cancel();
    };
  };

  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks okay except for not telling axios about the cancelToken or handling the cancellation error appropriately. [The Cancellation section of the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) has some details on this process that I've folded into your example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default useApi = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const request = async () => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    setLoading(true);
    
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, { cancelToken: source.token });
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        // don't update state in case component is dismounting
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error);
      }
    }

    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  };

  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I see though that you changed the await to `axios.get`. I had wanted to use this hook for all requests eg: post, get, put, patch which is why I thought to pass `url` and `options` to it. Would this not be possible?

Comment: @Iggy'sPop You can do that, but when using axios as a function (e.g. `axios(…)`) [there is only a single argument for config](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig). You can't combine the method signature of `axios.get()` and `axios()`—it's one or the other. I recommend you swap `axios.get(url, options)` with `axios({ url, method: "…", cancelToken: source.token })`.

Comment: thanks again. I am having some trouble trying to actually use this hook now. I have `import useApi from "../hooks/useApi";
const { request, data, error, loading } = useApi;` and then `const responseData = useApi.request("http://localhost:8000/api/users");
    console.log(responseData);` but get an error default.request is not a function

Comment: @Iggy'sPop You should probably open a second question to share your code. At a glance: 1) `useApi` is a function; you need to call it like `useApi()` 2) you don't want to call `useApi.request(…)` since there is no `request` function on the `useApi` object. Since you're destructuring `request`, just call `request(…)` instead.